# How do I print out phone number in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a contact book using sqlite3 in python, but when I'm trying to insert my phone number as **integer type**, it appears that it will occur syntax error for octal integer, and when I'm putting the numbers into **string type**, the 0 is not printed. How can I input my phone number no matter in int or str?

```
import sqlite3
from math import ceil

conn = sqlite3.connect("contact_book.db")

c = conn.cursor()


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE contact_book(
            name text,
            address text,
            phone_number integer,
            email address text
            )""")

conn.commit()

def insert_contact_details(name, address, phone_number, email_address=None):
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO contact_book VALUES(:name, :address, :phone_number, :email_address)",
                  {'name': name, 'address': address, 'phone_number': str(phone_number), 'email_address': email_address})
```

Below is when I put phone number into int:

```
insert_contact_details("Durian", "Malaysia", 0123239588)

output:

SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

Below is when I put phone number into str type:

```
insert_contact_details("Durian", "Malaysia", "0123239588")

output:

[(Durian, Malaysia, 123239588, None)]
```

Comment: I assume that you should create your table with `phone_number` as a `text` field.

Comment: You can format numbers to a particular width with leading zeros. Then you need to store the width too.

Answer (score 1):

The phone number should always be a string/text type everywhere.

Phone numbers in practice are more like strings that happen to use digits, rather than numeric values. For example, "01676 533433" (not a real number) is a valid phone number in my part of the world. But it is not the same as 1676533433. Most languages would consider the leading zero to indicate that this is an octal value.

Comment: Without a whole bunch more explanation, this is just a highly opinionated comment, not a useful answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for pointing that out. Added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Phone number must be string type. The reason why is the head of them is zero. Integer on computer has no digit information, so can't express heads zeros.

In addition, <s>in Python, to write `0123` is regarded as octal number</s> `0123` is syntax error simply (thanks Jarvis!), so above error occurred.

Comment: Not exactly, doing something like `a = 0123` in python will generate a syntax error instead hinting to use the prefix `0o` to define an octal. In C however, you can directly do this `printf("%i", 0123);`